# Change vs code terminal font to non-monospace

Tags: terminal, visual-studio-code

Is it possible to change the vs code terminal font to a font that is non-monospace?

The font I am trying to use is `Melso LG L Regular for Powerline` .

When I try to change the `terminal.integrated.fontFamily` in the user settings I get this:

[image: terminal font]

Is there any way around this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This app killed 'DejaVu Sans Mono Powerline' in the last release. It becomes a not sweet candy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use below settings. It worked for me in VScode terminal in ubuntu.

```
{
    //"terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "'Ubuntu Mono derivative Powerline', 'fontawesome'",
    "terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "'Meslo LG M DZ for Powerline', 'fontawesome'",
    "terminal.integrated.fontSize": 16

}
```

Please also make sure that you have installed `powerline` and `fontawesome` icons packages properly otherwise it might not work.

Use any of the above settings but make sure that powerline variant is installed. Below is my terminals output from VSCode terminal.

[image]

My Vscode version:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer from [WitVault](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745409/witvault) did not solve the problem for me at first, but it was the foundation for my solution. Ubuntu 20.04 did not recognize `Meslo LG M DZ ...`. I had a look at Ubuntus fonts app and there I saw, that the fonts name is `MesloLGMDZ Nerd Font Mono`. Thus having a look at your OS font application might help to find the correct name of the font.

With these setting (in `settings.json`) it works for me:

```json
{
    "terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "MesloLGLDZ Nerd Font Mono",
    "terminal.integrated.fontSize": 14
}
```

To change `setting.json` press `shift` + `ctrl` + `P` and write `Open Setting` and press enter.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
"terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "MesloLGS NF",
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**